# Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json\nDETAIL: The input string ended unexpectedly

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman

I want to input data into a field with data type json from postman, but I got an error like above, here is my code :

```
foreach($request->body as $body)
            {
                if(!empty($body['id'])){
                    $approval_template_body     = \App\Models\ApprovalTemplateBody::find($body['id']);
                } 
                else {
                    $approval_template_body     = new \App\Models\ApprovalTemplateBody();
                }
                
                $approval_template_body->approval_template_head_id      = $approval_template_head->id;
                $approval_template_body->order_number                   = $body['order_number'];
                $approval_template_body->approver                       = str_replace("'", '"', $body['approver']);
                $approval_template_body->is_free_choice                 = $body['is_free_choice'] ? 1 : 0;
                $approval_template_body->is_free_choice_loop            = $body['is_free_choice_loop'] ? 1 : 0;
                $approval_template_body->can_multiple                   = $body['can_multiple'] ? 1 : 0;
                $approval_template_body->on_approve                     = $body['on_approve'];
                $approval_template_body->on_reject                      = $body['on_reject'];
                $approval_template_body->save();


            }
```

here is the data I want to input :

```
"approver": "[{'mst_mail_group_id':1},{'mst_mail_group_id':4}]",
```

I want replace the single quotes (') to be double quotes (")

and the error is on the line :

```
$approval_template_body->approver = str_replace("'", '"', $body['approver']);
```

I have found the solution, the solution is :
`$approval_template_body->approver    = json_encode(str_replace("'", '"', $body['approver']));`

Comment: what does $body['approver'] contains?

Comment: $body['apporver'] contains : "[{'mst_mail_group_id':1},{'mst_mail_group_id':4}]"

Comment: "the error is on the line" - what does that mean? Which kind of error are you facing? What have you tried to resolve it? And how is that error related to Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for helping sir, I have found the solution, the solution is :

```
$approval_template_body->approver   = json_encode(str_replace("'", '"', $body['approver']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may receive the error, because you are trying to use str replace on a json object.

Try this:

```
$approval_template_body->approver = str_replace("'", '"', (string) $body['approver']);
```

Comment: thank you for helping sir, I have found the solution, the solution is : ```$approval_template_body->approver = json_encode(str_replace("'", '"', $body['approver']));```

Comment: I am glad you managed to solve it! You may post your own answer below.